# Is it possible compare two excel files, using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, comparison

I would like to know if using VBA I can compare two similar excel files and shows the differences highlighting the background of cells or rows with different colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through all the cells and make simple comparison, and highlight (change background color) cells that did not match.

Comment: @Cornelius: Have you actually tried this "looping through cells"? If you have, then your code is probably still running...