# Comparing Cells Between Worksheets, Range Doesn't Start on A1

Tags: vba, excel

Leveraging the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387929/vba-macro-to-compare-all-cells-of-two-excel-files), I was able to build a VBA macro to compare cells between worksheets to suit my purposes. However, until now, I didn't test it with a range that doesn't start at A1.

When giving a range like B1:X50, I encounter an issue where the LBound of the column dimension of the sheet array is 1 while the column at the start of the given range is 2 (B). Here's a portion of the code I'm working with:

```
'Define the range to be checked
strRangeToCheck = Summary_ws.Range("I2").Value

'Store the range to be checked on each sheet in an array
varSheetA = New_Data_ws.Range(strRangeToCheck)
varSheetB = Old_Data_ws.Range(strRangeToCheck)

'Clear current highlighted cells on data tabs
New_Data_ws.Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
Old_Data_ws.Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone

'Initialize counter
Counter = 0
Counter_rng.Value = Counter

For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
        On Error GoTo Err_Handler
        If IsError(New_Data_ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value) Or IsError(Old_Data_ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value) Then
            Counter = Counter + 1
            Error_Flag = True
            Call Flag_Changes
        ElseIf varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) And _
                Len(varSheetA(iRow, iCol)) = Len(varSheetB(iRow, iCol)) Then
                'Cells are identical and lengths match
                'Do Nothing
        Else 'Cells are different
            Counter = Counter + 1 'increment counter
            Error_Flag = False
            Call Flag_Changes
        End If
    Next iCol
Next iRow
```

I'm able to evaluate the strRangeToCheck to determine if it starts at column A or not. Based on that determination, would it then be possible to manually set the LBound of the sheet to match the starting column in strRangeToCheck?

Comment: this line would create a problem for you since it is only one cell `strRangeToCheck = Summary_ws.Range("I2").Value` Your range is always one cell or it could be more than one cell?

Comment: That cell contains a string provided by the user, like A1:Z100. If they give an invalid range, an error is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the question "would it then be possible to manually set the LBound of the sheet to match the starting column", the answer is no.  `Range.Value` will always return an array with a lower bound of 1 - Excel is responsible for creating the returned array, and you can't change that behavior via VBA (and wouldn't want to even if you could for various other reasons).

The solution is to create a `Range` from the passed address as an intermediate step before you pull the `.Value`'s into your arrays:

```
'Store the range to be checked on each sheet in an array
Dim newRange As Range
Dim oldRange As Range
Set newRange = New_Data_ws.Range(strRangeToCheck)
Set oldRange = Old_Data_ws.Range(strRangeToCheck)
varSheetA = newRange.Value
varSheetB = oldRange.Value
```

Then instead of using `Worksheet.Cells` in the loop, use `Range.Cells`.  If you need to convert that to worksheet addressing, you find the offset from `A1` from the first `Row` in the `Range`.  Using your example of `B1:X50`:

```
Dim example As Range
Set example = Sheet1.Range("B1:X50")
Debug.Print example.Columns(1).Column   '<-- column 2
Debug.Print example.Rows(1).Row         '<-- row 1
```

Note that in your code above, you're only using the worksheet indexing on a single line (although I have no clue what you're doing in `Call Flag_Changes`):

> ```
> If IsError(New_Data_ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value) Or IsError(Old_Data_ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value) Then
> ```

You don't need to do this at all.  `New_Data_ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value` is the exact same thing as `varSheetA(iRow, iCol)`.  That's why you pull it into an array, right?  Just replace that line with this:

```
If IsError(varSheetA(iRow, iCol)) Or IsError(varSheetB(iRow, iCol)) Then
```

Finally, you didn't include the declarations for `iRow` and `iCol`, but judging by the Hungarian notation if they're declared as `Integer` you need to change them to `Long` to avoid overflow errors.  If they ***are*** declared as `Long`, that's yet another argument against not using Hungarian notation to begin with...

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was able to get it to work. Also, I was completely ignorant to the Hungarian notation. That being said, `iRow` and `iCol` were defined as `Long`, but I will update the code to comply with naming standards. I'll post my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant way to implement the advice, but here's working code, thanks to Comintern:

```
'Store the range to be checked on each sheet in an array
Set newRange = New_Data_ws.Range(strRangeToCheck)
Set oldRange = Old_Data_ws.Range(strRangeToCheck)
varSheetA = newRange.Value
varSheetB = oldRange.Value

'Variables used to track difference between array start and given range start
row_diff = newRange.Rows(1).Row - 1
col_diff = newRange.Columns(1).Column - 1

'Loop through given range
For rngRow = newRange.Rows(1).Row To newRange.Rows.Count + row_diff
    arrRow = rngRow - row_diff 'increment row of array being evaluated
    For rngCol = newRange.Columns(1).Column To newRange.Columns.Count + col_diff
        arrCol = rngCol - col_diff 'increment column of array being evaluated
        On Error GoTo Err_Handler
        If IsError(varSheetA(arrRow, arrCol)) Or IsError(varSheetB(arrRow, arrCol)) Then
            Counter = Counter + 1
            Error_Flag = True
            Call Flag_Changes
        ElseIf varSheetA(arrRow, arrCol) = varSheetB(arrRow, arrCol) And _
                Len(varSheetA(arrRow, arrCol)) = Len(varSheetB(arrRow, arrCol)) Then
                'Cells are identical and lengths match
                'Do Nothing
        Else 'Cells are different
            Counter = Counter + 1 'increment counter
            Error_Flag = False
            Call Flag_Changes
        End If
    Next rngCol
Next rngRow
```

In my Flag_Changes sub, I'm just doing things like highlighting the different cells on either sheet, printing the address of that cell, printing the values of each cell, and the difference (if the cells are numeric).